# Redis bitwise key

Tags: redis, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to implement some bitwise operation on keys in redis.
I have to store let's say 
key            value
12:CA          foo
12:US          bar
42:CA          tag

And I'm trying to be able to query all with CA or all with 12
Is this even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mis-interpreting the question, but if you have key => values like

```
12:CA => foo
12:US => bar
42:CA => tag
```

And you want to pull all keys matching CA, or 12, then you can just use the keys operator along with a wildcard

```
keys *:CA
keys 12:*
```

**NOTE** This only returns the matching keys.  To get the values, you need to use the returned keys.

Comment: Oh really ?? I really didn't know I could use wildcard like that ! You truly made my day thanks !

Comment: Another note:  Using the wildcard can be *extremely* slow.  If your data model will allow it, and your number of keys will get large, you might want to consider using a Hash instead.

Comment: Yes I thought about this ... I'm gonna have a serious performance issue ... I'm gonna rechek my model but I'm pretty sure I'm gonna have a large set of data.